# Reverse algorithm with mod

Tags: algorithms

[Program algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFe2u.png)

So there is an algoritm. It used a certain number N and got the number R. We were informed what the number R was received. Knowing this number, we need to get the number N that was involved for the algorithm. It is necessary to obtain the minimum number N that would be suitable for this case. What should I do when I need a reverse such algorithm?

Comment: Generally, I'd say you have 2 options. One is to understand what the algorithm does, in which case it should become rather easy to understand how to "reverse" it when possible. @lhf already explained the algorithm, so it's pretty straightforward to reverse it now. The other way would be to blindly find an inverse to each individual operation of the algorithm. Can't think of any other way right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular algorithm computes the (reverse) representation of $N$ in base $5$ as a decimal number.
That is, if $N=(d_1 d_2 \dots d_n)_5$ then $R=(d_n \dots d_2 d_1)_{10}$.